# Change button image onclick

Tags: javascript, replace

I have this code to change from image 1 to image 2. How can I make it change from image 2 to image 3, and back to image 1? Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()"><img id="myImg" src="image1.gif" width="107"     height="98"></button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
document.getElementById("myImg").src="image2.gif";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/9R2J7/1/

```
var img_array = ['http://placehold.it/100x100/green', 'http://placehold.it/100x100/blue', 'http://placehold.it/100x100/red'];
i = 0;

function myFunction() {
    i++;
    document.getElementById("myImg").src = img_array[i];
    if (i == img_array.length - 1) {
        i = -1;

    }

}
```

Comment: nice :) .. you might wanna add the "var" on first init :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
function myFunction()
{
    if( document.getElementById("myImg").src == "image1.gif" ){
        document.getElementById("myImg").src = "image2.gif";
    }
    elseif( document.getElementById("myImg").src == "image2.gif" ){
        document.getElementById("myImg").src = "image3.gif";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("myImg").src = "image1.gif";
    }

}
```

It's not very elegant, but it could be a solution.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

## Using jQuery.

change your html to something of the sort:

```
<button id="change-img"><img ... /></button>
```

Then you can add an onclick to the `#change-img` element. In your jQuery, add

```
$('#change-img').click(function() {
    var image = $('#myImg');
    var imgNum = image.attr('src').split('.')[0].replace('image', ''); // gets the number
    imgNum = (imgNum % 3) + 1;
    image.attr( { 'src' : 'image' + imgNum + '.gif' } ); // selects image, changes source
});
```

And there you have it.

Made a demo, similar to what you'd like to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/94VKa/.

Comment: "*if you're using jQuery, which all of us highly recommend*" - do we? I quite like native JavaScript, personally...

Answer (score 0):

One further approach:

```
// initialise the array, using array-literal syntax:
var img_array = ['http://placehold.it/100x100/green',
                 'http://placehold.it/100x100/blue',
                 'http://placehold.it/100x100/red'];

function myFunction() {
   // finding where in the 'img_array' the current src is to be found:
   var current = img_array.indexOf(this.src);

   // updating the src of the clicked element, to either the next element in
   // the array (if 'current + 1' does *not* evaluate to equal the length of the
   // array, or to the first element in the array if 'current + 1' *does* equal
   // the length of the array:
   this.src = img_array[current + 1 === img_array.length ? 0 : current + 1];
}

// getting a reference to the element to click on,
// add an event-listener to 'listen' for that event, and execute the
// named function:
document.getElementById('myImg').addEventListener('click', myFunction);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9R2J7/2/).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).
- [Conditional ('ternary') operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).